# Where can I get Windows checked build?

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, device-driver

I'm developing a file system driver.
I use free build Windows as a target machine.
If I could get a checked build of Windows, I think I get more convenient. Isn't it.

But I do not know even where I can get it. Does it need a cost?
And what are the benefits I can get, when I use it.

Comment: Do you have an MSDN subscription?

Comment: But my company does. I was able to get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checked builds are available to MSDN subscribers from the MSDN download website.

The benefits are that when you attach a kernel debugger to debug your driver, you will gets lots of extra debugging information sent to the debug console, especially if you call any function with invalid parameters, it will be caught closer to the actual error because every function does parameter checking (that's the *checked* part of checked build) and print a warning.

[Here is a link with more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543450.aspx)

And a description of one of the checked builds available on MSDN:

> **Windows 7 Checked/Debug Build (x86) - DVD (English)**
>
> File Name:
> en_windows_7_checked_build_dvd_x86_398742.iso
>
> Date Published (UTC): 8/14/2009
> 9:55:36 AM
>
> Last Updated (UTC):
> 5/21/2010 8:22:29 AM
>
> Available to Levels: MSDN OS
> (VL); VS Pro with MSDN Pro (VL); VS
> Pro with MSDN Premium (Empower); MSDN
> OS (Retail); Developer AA; VS Pro with
> MSDN (Retail); MSDN Universal
> (Retail); VSTS Team Suite (VL); VSTS
> Architecture (VL); VS Premium with
> MSDN (MPN); VSTS Test (VL); VS Pro
> with MSDN Premium (MPN); MSDN
> Universal (VL); VSTS Database (VL); VS
> Pro with MSDN Premium (Retail); VSTS
> Test (Retail); VSTS Development
> (Retail); VSTS Architecture (Retail);
> VSTS Team Suite (Retail); VSTS
> Database (Retail); BizSpark Admin;
> BizSpark; VS Pro with MSDN Embedded
> (Retail); VS Pro with MSDN Embedded
> (VL); VS Test Pro with MSDN (VL); VS
> Ultimate with MSDN (VL); VS Premium
> with MSDN (VL); VS Pro with MSDN (VL);
> VS Test Pro with MSDN (Retail); MSDN
> Essentials; VS Premium with MSDN
> (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN
> (Retail); MSDN for Action Pack; VS
> Ultimate with MSDN (MPN); VS Ultimate
> with MSDN (NFR FTE);

Comment: Thanks Ben. It seems very nice. Does Every driver developer use it, by the way? Just curious.

Comment: It would be good for every driver developer to use it, because the checked build catches some problems that don't cause an outright crash.  Kernel debugging works on retail builds too, you just don't get as good information.  BTW, the kernel debugger itself IS free: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx

Comment: Fortunately, my company subscribes it. So I was able to get Win7 32bit checked image from MSDN. But when I install it in my VMWare7, it always dies with BSOD when it is being installed. I don't want to give up here. T.T

Comment: I would recommend contacting vmware for help if Windows 7 won't install properly on their virtual machine.  Or start another question here, and give details on the exact configuration of your virtual machine and the error message you get.  You might also NOT use "Easy Install" or whatever it is that types in the serial number for you.