# Where can I get checked builds for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, debugging, msdn

My question is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4362395), which was for Windows 7, except that I *do* have an MSDN Pro subscription and I have previously fetched checked builds of Windows.

I'd like to install the checked build for kernel debugging as I have done many times in the past with older Windows versions.

The strange thing is that Windows 10 checked build symbols *are* available. Have a look:

[image: Results for "checked" on MSDN downloads, limited display to Windows 10]

Strangely enough older versions such as Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 (also the respective server versions) have both symbols for the checked builds and installation media. Here the results for Windows 8 and 8.1:

[image: Results for "checked" on MSDN downloads, limited display to Windows 8 and 8.1]

So my question is: where may I find the installation media for checked builds of Windows 10?

Comment: If you have an MSDN subscription, someone is paying good money for it. Call the tech support hotline, demand an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm paying good money for it ;) ... let me try to find the hotline number for my country. Good idea.

Comment: Just to update everybody. The support was of no help whatsoever. I have yet to hear back from them concerning a final verdict of when or where such a checked build will be made available.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, did you get the answer from the tech support?

Comment: @LeonidFirdman: nope, didn't receive anything further. Another attempt to check with the online concierge also left me empty-handed.

Comment: Windows 10 build 1511 (checked/debug build) is up on MSDN, both US and N variants

Comment: @GregC So for the two year old version we have checked builds ... yay! Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: It won't even install, have to roll back the clock for it to work.  Cheering in excitement