# Where can I get Windows 10 Checked Builds?

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-10, kernel, msdn

I am hoping to get started developing drivers for Windows 10. I can start working on them now, but in order to be able to debug them, I understand that I need to be using a checked build of Windows.

There has been some discussion on this:

- [Where can I get Windows checked build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362395/where-can-i-get-windows-checked-build?noredirect=1&lq=1)          - Answered 2010
- [Where can I find the debug symbols Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480434/where-can-i-find-the-debug-symbols-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)  - Answered 2015
- [Where can I get checked builds for Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940134/where-can-i-get-checked-builds-for-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)  - Answered 2016

These answers all seem a bit outdated. I say this, because they all mention an absence of a checked build released by Microsoft. However, [the MSDN article on installing the checked build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/installing-the-complete-checked-build) -- which is updated more recently than these answers -- explains (or at least tries to) how to get the checked build.

It says

> Use the checked build distribution medium to install the checked build.

[There is a github issue up on this as well](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/issues/1523), but I and apparently many others have no clue what the "checked build distribution medium" is.

So, now that we are in a new decade from all of these questions, discussions, and issue tracking, how does one acquire a checked build of Windows 10 in 2020? Let's assume we do not have an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way, you must have MSDN subscription (now it called Visual Studio subscription)

Comment: The fact that it is called a visual studio subscription suggests that it is tied to a visual studio license. Is this the case? Could I get the checked build with something like a student or trial license for visual studio?

Comment: Continuing from my last comment, it looks like the answer is no, but it is tied to a visual studio license. I ended up needing a license for Visual Studio Professional, and with that I was able to locate and download the checked ISO and symbols.

Comment: I looked at my Visual Studio Subscriptions Enterpise account and the latest Debug/Checked build which is standalone is on 1511. (from 2015), i think all of the builds was joined into one ISO